# Create a proxy server on my home router to route all remote client traffic

Tags: networking, proxy, nginx, openwrt

I have a problem creating a proxy server on my Open WRT router. Unfortunately I can't install squid due to insufficient system memory of the Open WRT router but I can install NGINX on it. The problem is that I don't know about nginx.

I want remote clients (e.g. a smartphone or a computer) that have a public IP X.X.X.X to connect to my HTTP home proxy server via my public IP address Y.Y.Y.Y, a port of my choice, a username and password, and I would also like all remote client traffic to be routed through the proxy and therefore be visible on the internet with the public IP address of my home network.

I know that it can be a security problem and that it would be better to use a VPN like Open VPN or WireGuard which by the way I have already configured in my router, but I also need to configure a proxy. I need help with configuring nginx. Any alternative is welcome, my only aim is just to remotely use my home public IP address with a proxy server.

Comment: OpenWrt questions are best asked on the [OpenWrt Forum](https://forum.openwrt.org) since you'll be asking to a specific target audience and will get an answer faster than on StackExchange. You may also want to check out the relevant [OpenWrt Wiki](https://openwrt.org/docs/start) pages. General info: the default `uhttpd` web server should be used over `nginx`, unless there's a specific reason for `nginx`, as it's a much larger package. For small ROM sizes, extroot can be used to move the firmware to a USB drive (wiki). For WAN passthrough, use Wireguard or OpenVPN, not a proxy server - see Wiki

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply and the extra information regarding the open wrt memory space. For the WAN passthrough I already have a wireguard server that works very well and fast but for reasons of convenience, because I have to manage a large number of clients and also for other reasons, I need to create a proxy server that performs the same wireguard function i.e. route all client traffic to a proxy server so that clients acquire the public ip address of my network and can navigate with that public ip address. I asked for help in this forum mainly because I'm not very familiar with nginx.